# The norm of Gaussian integers and the irreducible element $ 1 + i $.

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory

**Note:** Let $ \text{N}(a + bi) \stackrel{\text{df}}{=} a^{2} + b^{2} $.

Observe that $ \text{N}(1 + i) = 2 $.

Is it always true that if $ 1 + i $ divides a Gaussian integer, then the norm of $ 1 + i $ divides the norm of that Gaussian integer? For instance, $ 1 + i \mid 3 + 3 i $ and $ 2 \mid 18 $, but $ 1 + i \nmid 4 + i $ and $ 2 \nmid 17 $. It thus seems that if $ a \equiv b ~ (\text{mod} ~ 2) $, then $ 1 + i \mid a + b i $.

Comment: Yes, it is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually have two claims written, both of which are true.

The first is:

> Is it always true that if $1+i$ divides a gaussian integer then the norm of $1+i$ divides norm of the gaussian integer.

Here's the proof: Suppose $1+i \mid a+bi$, meaning $(1+i)z=a+bi$ for some Gaussian integer $z$. Taking absolute values gives $2|z|^2 = a^2+b^2$, as needed.

Your last statement is the *converse* of your earlier claim:

> so It seems that if $a \equiv b \pmod 2$ then $(1+i) \mid (a+bi)$

This follows by observing that $1+i \mid 2, 2i, 1+i$ and then noting that any such $a+bi$ can be written as a sum of elements in $\{2, 2i, 1+i\}$.